# How to make the last Item a leaf when TreePick is populate by a DataSource?

Tags: smartgwt

I'm using SmartGWT 2.5.

I would like to use the same example showed [here](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#picktree_combobox_category)

As you can see for the Department menu, we can 'setCanSelectParentItems(false)
`For Category menu, if we`setCanSelectParentItems(false)`, it allows us to select only the null item with label`[Empty Menu]`.

I would like to make the last Item a leaf when TreePick is populate by a DataSource? And then disable parent selection with `mCategory.setCanSelectParentItems(false);`

Could you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    categoryItem.setDataSource(dataSource);  
    categoryItem.setEmptyMenuMessage("No Sub Categories");  
    categoryItem.setCanSelectParentItems(true);          
    categoryItem.setLoadDataOnDemand(false);
    dataSource.fetchData();
```

**// Set Load on Demand to false**